# iTunes movies inside virtual machine

Tags: macos, itunes, vmware

I am running macOS High Sierra inside VMware (Professional Version 10.1.2) on top of High Sierra.
Inside the virtual machine I am using a different apple id (I am not sure this is relevant here).

The problem is that when playing a iTunes movie inside the vm then I have no sound and screen of the iTunes movie window is black.
I see, however, that the movie "progresses".
I have neither of these problems with YouTube videos inside the vm.

Is there a way to fix this *iTunes inside VM problem* ?

Here is a screen shot using grab.
[image: Screen shot of VMware window]

Comment: It is possibly the DRM associated with the movie. Ever notice you can't screen cap a DVD or movie in iTunes? I would bet that this issue is related as I have heard of this issue before.

Comment: Maybe try reauthenticating the machine to iTunes.

Comment: Can you try 2 things and reply with results? 1. Take a screenshot (with Grab) on the VM. Does the movie show up there? 2. Set up screen sharing. Can you see it from there?

Comment: I took the screen shot with grab. Video is also black there.

Comment: Could you add a source for your remark on DRM?

Comment: iTunes requires a 3d-accellerating GPU for playback, and Fusion cannot offer that. (If you look at the settings for the VM, you'll see that it's not possible for that guest OS.) I don't have a solution for this, and would like to know one.